# Get UID of the current record being added/edited in TYPO3 Backend forms for a Plugin

Tags: forms, typo3, backend

Assuming I have a Plugin `MyExtPlugin` and has a record `MyExtPlugin_Record_A` and this record has a field `status`.

The DB field of `MyExtPlugin_Record_A` are `uid,name,status` .

For status in TCA form:

```
'status'=>array(
          'type' => 'user'
          'userFunc' => 'EXT:userClass.specialFunction'   
          )
```

My specialFunction should do something like this:

```
   current_uid_of_record= #get current uid of the record;
   current_status= #get status for current_uid_of_record
   if (current_status==0)
     return 'Pending';
   return 'Approved';
```

**Question:** How do I get that current Uid of that record which is being added or edited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function specialFunction($PA, $fobj) {
  $current_uid_of_record = $PA['row']['uid'];

  // ...
}
```

Be aware though that the **UID is never 0**. It's either a number >0 or a temporary UID which is a string starting with letters.

Comment: I see you made some changes but it's rather irrelevant for my answer. My example just demonstrates that the data are in `$PA['row']` array. It's really up to you how you use it.